# Build JSON : POST With array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hi i want make a Json for my POST with a array who contain all my modifications like :

```
    var tabname = ["test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"];
    var tabID = [1, 2, 3];

    to build at the end a json like that : 

    ----------------- HOW MAKE THAT ??---------------------
    - var item = {
    -     "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    -     "test 1" : 1 //tabname[i]: tabID[i]
    -     "test 2" : 2 //tabname[i]: tabID[i]
    -     "test 3" : 3 //tabname[i]: tabID[i]
    - };
    ------------------HOW MAKE THAT ??---------------------



    var data  = JSON.stringify(item);


$.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",                
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
```

Thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = { "__metadata" : { "type" : itemType } };

for (var i = 0; i < tabname.length; i++) {
    item[tabname[i]] = tabID[i];
}

var data = JSON.stringify(item);
```

Comment: it works !!! thx